# Thread Safe SqlDependency

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

Hi at the moment I am using UnitOfWork repository pattern and made changes to my get call such that if memory doesn't have the query stored, it'll query and also store the query results in memory using MemoryCache. While storing it to memory cache I've set up so that sql dependencies is also implemented.

The current issue I have is that if the query is ran in a task/background thread, the sql notification doesn't seem thread safe and I'm not returned a notification to the main UI thread. May I ask how abouts do I do that? If SqlDependency can't be done in another thread, is there a way to tell the main thread to set up the notification?

Sql Dependy Code is from an online project can be found here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-SqlDependency-5c0da0b3

Person Repository Code

```
private static readonly List<ImmediateNotificationRegister<Person>> NotificationRegisters =
    new List<ImmediateNotificationRegister<Person>>();

public PersonRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    : base(context)
{ }

public IEnumerable<Person> GetActive()
{
    return Get(x => x.Active, o => o.OrderBy(x => x.CorrespondenceName));
}

public IEnumerable<Person> Get(
    Expression<Func<Person, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<Person>, IOrderedQueryable<Person>> orderBy = null,
    int? numberOfEntities = null,
    IEnumerable<string> includeProperties = null, bool useCache = false)
{
    IQueryable<Person> query = DbSet;
    List<Person> result;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        query = orderBy(query);
    }

    var actualNumberOfEntities = int.MaxValue;

    if (numberOfEntities.HasValue)
    {
        actualNumberOfEntities = Math.Max(1, numberOfEntities.Value);
    }

    if (!useCache)
    {
        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query,
                (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
        }

        return query.AsExpandable().Take(actualNumberOfEntities).ToList();
    }

    if (MemoryCache.Default[query.ToString()] == null)
    {

        var notification = new ImmediateNotificationRegister<Person>(Context, query);
        notification.OnChanged += NotificationOnChanged;
        NotificationRegisters.Add(notification);

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query,
                (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
        }
        result = query.AsExpandable().Take(actualNumberOfEntities).ToList();
        MemoryCache.Default[query.ToString()] = result;
        return result;
    }

    return ((IEnumerable<Person>)MemoryCache.Default[query.ToString()]).ToList();
}
```

Comment: [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) is not thead safe. See remarks in documentation.

Comment: "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." Is this what you are referring to? Looks like it's safe to a certain extent @JeroenHeier

Comment: @Master that blob of text is on almost every class page. it is the default text. Also you are only using "instance memembers" in your code, so you have no gaurntees

Comment: I don't see any SqlDependency code here. Where is it?

Comment: Hi @usr it's embedded within ImmediateNotificationRegister and it can be found within https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-SqlDependency-5c0da0b3/view/SourceCode#content. I could paste it here but I think it would be code overload.

Comment: You really need to post short and complete code. No chance for an answer otherwise.

Comment: @usr Okay! I'll think about how to drastically reduce it.